# JOIN the same table

Tags: sql, select, informix

Hi I have table badge which has columns `facility` and `date` (other columns are not important).
I want to `select count(*)` which should look like this:

```
DATE       | FACILITY 4 COUNT | FACILITY 1 COUNT
12/12/2012 | 234              |  647
```

I wrote two separate queries for `facility` 1 and 4 but how to join it to one Query;

```
SELECT
    date,
    COUNT(*)
    FROM      badge
    WHERE     facility = 3
    AND       xtype = 19
    AND       date BETWEEN 'some_date' AND 'some_date'
    GROUP BY  date
```

another query differs only in the value of facility.

**EDIT:** It's informix database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN facility = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `Facility 3 Count`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN facility = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `Facility 1 Count`
FROM      badge
WHERE     xtype = 19 AND      
          date BETWEEN 'some_date' AND 'some_date'
GROUP     BY  date
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(case when facility = 1 then 1 else 0 end) "FACILITY 1 COUNT",
       SUM(case when facility = 4 then 1 else 0 end) "FACILITY 4 COUNT"
FROM      badge
WHERE     (facility = 1 OR facility = 4)
AND       xtype = 19
AND       date BETWEEN 'some_date' AND 'some_date'
GROUP BY  date
```

Comment: I would add AND (facility = 1 OR facility = 4) to the where clause to make the query more efficient.